# How to stop replacing previous entries in shared preferences?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sharedpreferences

My code used to replace the previous entries and I realized I needed to use different keys for storing in shared preferences. Now my code does not output anything in the listview. please help

**Java code where I ask for information about the person (name, favcolor, favfood)**

```
public class personInfo extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText editText_name;
    EditText editText_favfood;
    EditText editText_favcolor;
    Button button_save;
    static int count = 0;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_personinfo);
        Log.d(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(), "onCreate");

        editText_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_name);
        editText_favcolor = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_favcolor);
        editText_favfood = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_favfood);
        button_save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_save);


        button_save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                count++;
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("ENTRIES", 0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

                    editor.putString("name" + count, editText_name.getText().toString());
                    editor.putString("favcolor" + count, editText_favcolor.getText().toString());
                    editor.putString("favfood" + count, editText_favfood.getText().toString());

                    editor.apply();
                    editor.putInt("numOfEntries", count);


                Intent it = new Intent(personInfo.this, listOfPeople.class);
                startActivity(it);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

**Java code, page that is supposed to display the entries**

```
public class listOfPeople extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<listEntry> list = new ArrayList<>();
    listEntry le;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView_persons);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("ENTRIES", MODE_PRIVATE);
        int count = sharedPreferences.getInt("numOfEntries", 0);

        for(int i = 1; i <= count; i++){
            String nameValue = sharedPreferences.getString("name" + i, "");
            String favcolorValue = sharedPreferences.getString("favcolor" + i, "");
            String favfoodValue = sharedPreferences.getString("favfood" + i, "");

            le = new listEntry(nameValue, favcolorValue, favfoodValue);
            list.add(le);
        }

        personListAdapter adapter = new personListAdapter(this, R.layout.entryrow, list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: But this is consider as bad practice, with this kind of scenario you should use sqlite database for easy and convenient CRUD operation and can be a useful for future projects

Answer (score 0):

You are applying (saving) preferences before putting `count`

```
 editor.apply();
 editor.putInt("numOfEntries", count);
```

Just put before applying

```
 editor.putInt("numOfEntries", count);
 editor.apply();
```

Answer (score 0):

call editor.apply() after editor.putInt("numOfEntries", count);

```
editor.putInt("numOfEntries", count);
editor.apply();
```